# SwiftUI: External screen view not updating after app comes back to foreground

Tags: swiftui, uiscenedelegate

I need to use external screen do lyrics projection (I develop app for chords & lyrics). Everything works fine until I move app to background and back to foreground.
View on external screen is not updating (on appear it shows correct number and then does not update).

You can see the problem here: https://media.justchords.online/SwiftUIExtScreenProblem.mov

Settings in Info.plist:
EnableMultipleWindows = YES
SceneConfiguration / External Display Session Role Non-Interactive:
Configuration Name = External
Delegate Class Name = $(PRODUCT_NAME).ExternalSceneDelegate

Test view for external screen:

```
struct ExternalScreenTestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var counter = TestCounter.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(counter.count.description)
            .font(.system(size: 50))
    }
}

class TestCounter: ObservableObject {
    private var timer: Timer?
    @Published var count = 1
    
    static var shared:TestCounter = TestCounter()
    
    init() {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.count += 1
        }
    }
    
}
```

My SceneDelegate:

```
final class ExternalSceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var controller: UIHostingController<ExternalScreenTestView>?
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene,
               willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
               options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let scene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {
            return
        }
        
        let content = ExternalScreenTestView()
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        controller = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        window?.rootViewController = controller
        window?.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Timer Can’t survive background for long. Look into TimelineView.

Comment: Thank you. Timer lives. I can see correct number everytime app comes to foreground. But not updating while view is displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately since `View`s are structs they have no lifetime so you can't use `DispatchQueue.main.async` because the struct is gone by the time the closure is called. You either need to use `.task` that has an internal object, or make your own `@StateObject` or just use `TimelineView` that already implements an object  as lorem already said.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. So I wrapped timer into observable object and included the same view on both screens. Here is video, where you can see the problem: http://media.justchords.online/SwiftUIExtScreenProblem.mov